# Stack reverse and sort

Tags: java, sorting, stack

I have a data structure Stack.Where stack within a stack.

```
Stack<Stack<Integer>> stack = new Stack<>();
Stack<Integer> stackI1 = new Stack<>();
Stack<Integer> stackI2 = new Stack<>();
Stack<Integer> stackI3 = new Stack<>();
```

I already push some element into it.Look like[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
  Now I want to sort those element respect to 1st value means respect to 1,4,7. How is it possible?Unable to find build in function. Unable to sort using Collection.sort. So where will be the alternatives.Also want to reverse after sorting.But unable to reverse with build in function Collection.reverse. Please help me

Comment: If you want to sort, then you don't want a stack.

Comment: No, I need stack and then sort that stack.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - the definition of a stack is first-in last-out behaviour; why would you want to sort that?

Comment: Take the things out, sort them, put them back in order.

Comment: To implement A* algorithm for path finding.

Comment: I don't remember ever having to sort a stack for A*.  The way you explore paths should add everything in a sorted order

Comment: If I take things out it jumble my order. I have to maintain the order like 1 is always with 2 and 3. In my example maybe it doesn't matter. But think like that if I have a sub stack like [5,3,10] here the order matter. I cannot put 3 before 5. This is my restriction. I can only sort respect to 1st element.

Comment: The cell that it choose to move depend upon its cost. whose cost is smallest the robot move to that co- ordinate. Then again search for smallest cost and then again go towards the smallest cost co ordinate. So this 1st value of my stack like [1,2,3] 1 represent that smallest value.

Comment: The single `Stack`s might be OK but why the "surrounding" `Stack`? This more looks like a regular list you want to use here.

Comment: As a side note, what are you using stacks for in A*?  Shouldn't it be some form of heap/priority queue?

Comment: Firstly, I am not very confident in Java. Still trying to implement it. I was searching for A* for last 2 weeks. Not get any any better result. Lastly I decided that I implement it in Stack. But still some problem to implement it.

Comment: Looking at the question, it appears that the goal may be to merge 3 already sorted stacks into one reverse sorted stack, which would just use normal merge. To end up in order, merge the stacks to a temporary stack, then pop from the temp stack to the output stack to "unreverse" the order.

Comment: For a true stack based sort (using 3 or more stacks, one of which contains the original data, the other 2 are temp stacks), some variation of bottom up merge sort is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stack` extends `Vector` so you can use `List#sort` to resort a `Stack` (as mentioned in the comments, this is quite "unusual"). The values you provided resulted into an already "sorted" stack, so I changed that to show the effect the code has on it:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackSort {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Stack<Integer>> stacks = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> stackI1 = new Stack<>();
        stackI1.push(Integer.valueOf(1));
        stackI1.push(Integer.valueOf(2));
        stackI1.push(Integer.valueOf(3));
        Stack<Integer> stackI2 = new Stack<>();
        stackI2.push(Integer.valueOf(7));
        stackI2.push(Integer.valueOf(8));
        stackI2.push(Integer.valueOf(9));
        Stack<Integer> stackI3 = new Stack<>();
        stackI3.push(Integer.valueOf(4));
        stackI3.push(Integer.valueOf(5));
        stackI3.push(Integer.valueOf(6));

        stacks.push(stackI1);
        stacks.push(stackI2);
        stacks.push(stackI3);

        System.out.println(stacks);

        stacks.sort((stack1, stack2) -> {
            if (stack1.isEmpty()) {
                return stack2.isEmpty() ? -1 : 0;
            }
            if (stack2.isEmpty()) {
                return 1;
            }

            return stack1.get(0).compareTo(stack2.get(0));
        });

        System.out.println(stacks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiii!!! It's not working Cannot sort. Back me the stack value before sorting.

Comment: @RimaSur Here [TM] I get the following output from the two `System.out.println` in the code: `[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]]` before and `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` after calling `sort`. So what exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I wrote that for previous one. This one is perfectly alright. Thanks. Now if I want to reverse this whole answer or may be sorted in a reverse order what should I do? Please help me.

Comment: @RimaSur To sort in reverse, negate the sorting function, you can use `return stack2.get(0).compareTo(stack1.get(0));` for part of it

Comment: @RimaSur negate the values being returned in the comparison-block. Instead of `1` return `-1`and vice versa. And put a `-` before the last line to negate the result of the `compareTo` call

Comment: I change the code as follows :-----   stack.sort((stack1, stack2) -> {
            if (stack1.isEmpty()) {
                return stack2.isEmpty() ? 1 : 0;
            }
            if (stack2.isEmpty()) {
                return -1;
            }

            return stack1.get(0).compareTo(stack2.get(0));
        });

        System.out.println(stack);     Can you please elaborate it more specifically what do you mean by writing this [And put a - before the last line to negate the result of the compareTo call]

Comment: @RimaSur `return -stack1.get(0).compareTo(stack2.get(0));`

Comment: Thank You. Thank You So much. It's Working. No problem with the code. Thank you again. I was searching it for last 2 weeks. Thank you

Comment: public class New1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int cost = 1;
        int y = 0;
        int g = 0; int [] b=fun1(x,y,g,cost);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));}public static int[] fun1(int d, int b, int c,int f) {
        int [] a=new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            int x2=1,y2=1,g2=1;
             d = x2 + f;
             b = y2 + f;
            c = g2 + f;
            a[0]=d;
            a[1]=b;   a[2]=c;
}   return (a); }} The fun1 cannot recive the updated value in x,y,g?Where is the bug?

Comment: @RimaSur That doesn't look like a question related to this one. In that case please create a new question for this.

Comment: No it is related.I want to create a stack within a stack.Then taking a , for loop and update the values of the sub stack but want to append the new values where previous value is also retain. It's look like [[0,0,0] [1,1,1]].  and after input all values I will sort and reverse my main stack.But when ever I run my program it abolish previous value and write the new one like there is no existence of 0,0,0 only 1,1,1 is remain there.I doubt stack data structure is suitable for this operation!!

Comment: @RimaSur "No it is related.I want to create a stack within a stack.Then taking a , for loop and update the values of the sub stack but want to append the new values where previous value is also retain." The only common thing here is the wort `Stack` but nothing about sorting one. So please create a new question for this.